# Memory saving alternatives for Adjacency matrixes using vector of ints

Tags: c++, memory-management, image-segmentation, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to solve a image segmentation problem using BFS and Edmonds Karp algorithm, I am using a `vector<vector<int>> Adj_Matrix` as a data structure to save the Adnjacency matrix that keeps the vertical and horizontal links of the graph.

It's a undirected graph as such I think there might be better memory saving alternatives than having a full matrix of int vectors.

I'm doing

```
Adj_Matrix.reserve(totalV);
for (int i = 0; i < totalV; i++){
     Adj_Matrix[i].reserve(totalV);
}
```

to reserve memory for the data structure and then `Adj_Matrix.clear();`

But I'm running into memory problems and crashes when parsing and computing large (>800x800) matrixes. So I'm wondering what would be a better way of storing or representing these adjacency matrix that would save memory and time.

Comment: You could try storing it as a sparse matrix using Eigen. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html

Comment: 800x800 ints is like 2.5 megs.  Are you on constrained hardware? 8000x8000 would be 250 megs, 80000x80000 would be 25 gigs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adjacency matrix, you can use **adjacency lists**. The difference is when you don't have enough links for a particular vertex, its corresponding **adj_list[i] vector will need less elements** than the predefined totalV size it had in case of adjacency matrix. This will be helpful specially in cases of sparse graphs.

Further, you can encode your information to store more than one link in a single element of a vector such that you can later decode it, using techniques like **bit masking**.